# Navigation Bar not showing up at runtime iOS 8 Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uinavigationbar

Good day, needed some help. My Navigation bar can be seen in Story.board but not during runtime.

It was displaying well before I added an Embedded Tab Bar controller to the screen. Now I don't even know how to remove the Embeded Tab Bar controller.

Any help would be appreciated. :-)

(sorry my reputation too low and cannot post picture.)

Answer (score 2):

If you are instantiating the view programmatically, make sure you instantiate the storyboard ID for the NavigationController and not the View Controller itself. That was my issue..

Answer (score 1):

So I had exactly the same problem today and found that that it needs to be within a Navigation Controller in the story board hierarchy.

As well as this I found if you present something modally then this needs to be embed in another Navigation Controller too.

Hope this helps